# Editing classes on a div in CKEditor

Tags: wysiwyg

We are using the ckeditor_div_manager module on our Drupal 8 site to provide the Div Manager plugin on our CKEditor.

On of my content editors reports that, while it does allow her to add a wrapper div that has our pre-defined classes onto elements, there is no way with the widgets to edit existing divs to remove the class, or remove the div altogether. She has to go into the source and 'manually' pick out the wrapping div tags.

The only operation that this plugin/module provides is to add a new wrapping div; it explicitly says so in its dialog: "Create Div Container". When I click on an existing div in the editor, and click the widget icon, it's the same dialog, "Create Div Container", and it wraps a new div around the div I've selected. It doesn't provide editing options.

I looked around, and I didn't find anything specifically for this situation.

Is there a way I can configure our site so that our content editors can edit classes on divs, or delete wrapping divs, via the WYSIWYG, without editing the source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found out at least one way to edit and remove divs. We have a "Show Blocks" widget (not sure if that's stock or what).

[image]

This causes outlines to show for block elements:

[image]

Hover over the div, and then right-click to get a menu with edit and remove:

[image]